# Lower bound for $\frac{\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x+ty| }{|x|+|y|}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a $c>0$ such that $$c\leq \frac{\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x+ty| }{|x|+|y|}$$ for all real $x,y$.

I have tried a few things but none seem to give me anything useable.

If both $x,y$ have the same sign then the value of the RHS of the inequality is just $1$. So clearly $c\leq1$.

Also for any fixed $t$ the expression on the RHS is less than the sup. But I cant seem to use this either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this satisfy you?
$$
\frac{\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x+ty| }{|x|+|y|}=\frac{\max\{|x|,|x+y|\}}{|x|+|y|}
$$
and 
$$
\max\{|a|,|b|\}>\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}
$$
so:
$$
\frac{|x|+|x+y|}{2(|x|+|y|)}\leq \frac{\sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x+ty| }{|x|+|y|}
$$
if you are looking for a constant lower bound then you can get $c=1/4$ from that.

Comment: How do we get that $c$?

Comment: take the lower bound, set x=1, and examine the resulting function varying y, and you'll see that y=-1 leads the lowest value

Answer (score 1):

Note that the supremum is always attained either for $t=0$ or for $t=1$ and that the interesting case is $x>0,y<0$. Thus, we just need to find the best constant $c$ for which $\max(x,|x-y|)\ge c(x+y)$. It is also clear that we can multiply $x,y$ by the same constant without changing anything, so WLOG, $x=1$. From here I would just draw the graphs to see that $c=1/3$, so $c(1+y)$ touches $\max(1,|1-y|)$ at $y=2$ though analytic solutions are possible as well.